# Using Notations in Records

Tags: syntax, coq

The Coq manual ([Simultaneous definition of terms and notations](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#simultaneous-definition-of-terms-and-notations)) states

> Thanks to reserved notations, inductive, co-inductive, **record**, recursive and corecursive definitions can use customized notations.

I would like to define something like

```
Reserved Notation "A +' B" (at level 80).
Record foo T :=
  { add : T -> T ->T;
    commute a b : a +' b = b +' a 
      where "a +' b" := (add a b)
  }.
```

but I get

```
Error: Unknown interpretation for notation "_ +' _".
```

Comment: Putting the "where" clause after the record brings up an error message: "where clause not supported for records". This looks like a bug, either in the manual or in the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

One must define the notation before the first use in the `Record`, like this:

```
Reserved Notation "A +' B" (at level 60).
Record foo T :=
  { add : T -> T ->T where "A +' B" := (add A B);
    commute a b : a +' b = b +' a 
  }.
```